# How to assign a string from a list in python

Tags: python, string, list

I want to read from a list

```
data= ['hello','world','# ignorethis','xlable: somethingx','ylable: somethingy']
```

My goals:

1. I want to assign these strings in the list to different variable, so that I give `'hello'` to `x` and `'world'` to `y`, something like that.
2. Ignore the string with `#`.
3. Only read `somethingx` to a variable `z` instead of `'xlable: somethingx'`.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: Is the number of variables always fixed, or does it vary from list to list?

Comment: Pssh, easy: `x = data[0]`, `y = data[1]`, `z = "somethingx"`. Pardon the irony, but without more specific of an explanation what you are trying to achieve this, is all we can do.

Comment: Why program something when it cannot be generalized to any other situation?

Comment: I can understand that you want to filter/cleanup the list, but I can't see why you'd want to assign the values to different variables

Comment: Please, restate your problem in a way that we can help you figure out what you need. State it in general terms. You have a list: is it fixed? is it dynamic? do you know how the data will be organized? You want to put it into three variables, or three lists? What will you do with those variables afterwards?

Comment: Why so many people give me negative marks... the thing is that i want to make my program easier to modify if I want to fix my xlable and ylable from the text file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a list comprehension:

```
>>> data= ['hello','world','# ignorethis','xlable: somethingx','ylable: somethingy']
>>> x, y, z = [item.split(':')[-1].strip() for item in data 
                                                  if not item.startswith('#')][:3]
>>> x
'hello'
>>> y
'world'
>>> z
'somethingx'
```

**Explanation:**

1. `item.startswith('#')` filters the items that starts with `'#'`. If you want to check for `'#'` at any position in the string then use `if '#' not in item`.
2. `item.split(':')` splits the string at `':'` and returns a list:

**Example:**

```
>>> 'xlable: somethingx'.split(':')
['xlable', ' somethingx']
>>> 'hello'.split(':')
['hello']
```

---

In Python3 you can also do:

```
x, y, z, *rest = [item.split(':')[-1].strip() for item in data 
                                                 if not item.startswith('#')]
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, the thing is that i want to make my program easier to modify if I want to fix my xlable and ylable from the text file·